# How to install chrome on unregistered redhat

Tags: rhel

I can not install "Google Chrome" on my RedHat6 machine.

I used the following command:

```
yum -y install google-chrome-stable
```

The following error occurs:

```
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register
```

Comment: Have you contacted Red Hat on how to register and pay for your subscription management?

Comment: No, I hv not purchased the License.

Comment: AFAIK you should do so before you can download software from the Red Hat repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the box in place to CentOS, which is (almost) a drop-in replacement for RHEL and free.

Details are version-specific, see link below. Yum, rhel-release and the rhsm packages are yanked out and replaced with the CentOS bits.

https://www.pickysysadmin.ca/2014/07/15/how-to-convert-rhel-6-x-to-centos-6-x/